# Prefetch and merge two reverse foreign key of same model in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a problem, maybe somone has a solution for me.

I have two models:

```py
class Task(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "task"

class Rule(models.Model):
    
    to_task = models.ForeingKey(Task, related_name="to_task_rules")
    from_task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name="from_task_rules")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "rule"
```

I want to loop into tasks and display all concerned distinct rules by current task by prefetching `to_task_rules` and `from_task_rules` in a field `task_rules`, but without success

Django does not seems to provide way to do that. I try to make prefetch with to_attr="task_rules", but, we cannot use twice same name.

```py
# This solution does not work. to_attr cannot be have same name twice.
# In this case, i do not known how filter for having distinct results
Task.objects.prefetch(
    Prefetch("from_task_rule", queryset=Rule.objects.all(), to_attr="task_rules"),
    Prefetch("to_task_rule", queryset=Rule.objects.filter(...), to_attr="task_rules")
)
```

Anybody have an idea, excluded to prefetch during loop for preventing N+1 query ?

Thanks